# Invalid module format error on Raspberry. Kernel 3.10.25+

Tags: raspbian, kernel, modules

I am trying to install a module on my Raspberry Pi B+ running with Raspbian. To know the version of the Kernel I run the command `uname -a` and i got this:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

So I downloaded the same version of the kernel but without the **+**, the version 3.10.25 from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/095f493c4d532b0ced3aee22e2d5b2cea02aa773).
After compiling my module I run the `modinfo´ command and I got this:

```
vermagic: 3.10.25 preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv6
```

But I send the module to the the Raspberry withe the scp command but when I try to install the module with `insmod` I got an error:

```
Error: could not insert module tz-check.ko: Invalid module format
```

When I run a `dmesg | tail` I got this:

```
tz_check: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Any solution please?

Comment: It looks like the module was compiled against kernel headers that are meant for a different version of the kernel.  I think you said that you copied the compiled module to the Pi using scp.  Does that mean you compiled the module on a different computer?  If so, try compiling it on the Pi.

Comment: @mazianni The goal is to cross-compile. Why is there a problem with the kernel version ? I used 3.10.25 for compilation and for the kernel on the board